# How to store class type in a variable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm new to C#. I have two classes

```
public class TestA {
  
}

public class TestB {

}
```

I want to to something like this

```
var mode = 1;
var className = mode == 1 ? TestA : TestB;

var repository = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<className>();
```

How should I do this?

Comment: First of all u should be more specific.First it was 'how to put object inside object?' and now it's how to passed variable  as generic.  U can't pass variable as generic argument

Comment: Think about what the _static type_ of `var repository` would be if C# supported this kind of type-dynamism...

Comment: This part it's already wrong `var className = mode == 1 ? TestA : TestB`.  
TestA and TestB aren't the same type so you can't do this.
Read more about VAR before using it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class TestA :IRepoItem {
      
    }
    
    public class TestB :IRepoItem {

  
    }
    public class Repository<t>: where T: IRepoItem
    {
    }



    Repository<IRepoItem> repository;

    repository= mode == 1 ? _unitOfWork.GetRepository<TestA>():_unitOfWork.GetRepository<TestB>();
```

OR

```
 public class RepositoryFactory
{
  public Repository<IRepoItem> GetInstance(string itemName)
  {
    if(itemName==nameof(TestA))
    {
      return _unitOfWork.GetRepository<TestA>();
    }
    else if(itemName==nameof(TestB))
    {
      return _unitOfWork.GetRepository<TestB>();
    }
  }
}

    Repository<IRepoItem> repository;
    RepositoryFactory _factory = new RepositoryFactory(_unitOfWork);
    string className = mode == 1 ? nameof(TestA) : nameof(TestB);
    repository=_factory.GetInstance(className);
```